# How to perform add action in a form only one time, after update the record everytime

Tags: forms, cakephp, element

I have a form element. When I click the submit button it will add the data to the table.
that is working fine. But my need is to add data to the table only the first time, after each submission data should updated.how we can do this?

```
function add(){
  if(!empty($this->data)){
    $this->loadModel('Defineroute');
    $this->Defineroute->create();
    $this->Defineroute->save($route_data); //route_data is data from the form
  }
}
```

I have one more doubts, I have a view.ctp in the controller I have a view() function for that. But in the view.ctp I use one form element.

How we can write function for that element in the controller? When I try to write function, it shows the error missing view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePhp determines if it should *update* an existing record or *insert* a new record based on the presence of the primary key ('id') inside the data you're saving;

This will *insert* a new record:

```
$route_data = array(
    'Defineroute' => array(
        'name' => 'I am a new record'
    )
);

$this->Defineroute->save($route_data);
```

And this will *update* an existing record;

```
$route_data = array(
    'Defineroute' => array(
        'id'   => 123,
        'name' => 'I will update record with ID 123'
    )
);

$this->Defineroute->save($route_data);
```

To accommodate this in a single form, create the form inside your view/element and only add an input for the `id` field if you're editing an existing record

Also see [Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Comment: @SibinF that really depends on your situation; Where are you *retrieving* the existing data if you want to edit? How do you decide if you want to *edit* or *insert* a record? How do you 'select' the right record to edit?